# Check the current page is a view

Tags: views, 8, breadcrumbs

Is there a way to determine if you are on a view page, similar to   `\Drupal::request()->get('node')` used to check if the current page is a node page?

I need to adjust breadcrumbs for view generated pages with `hook_system_breadcrumb_alter()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use the name of the current route:

```
$current_route_name = \Drupal::service('current_route_match')->getRouteName();
```

The route names from views are built like this `view.[view_name].[display_id]`.

You can list the existing routes with Drupal Console:

```
drupal router:debug
```

Comment: Oh nice - is there a way to 'see' the View as well? I'd like to append the View title to the breadcrumb.

Comment: You can get the title from the titleResolver. See for example PathBasedBreadcrumbBuilder.

Comment: Once again, your depth of knowledge on 8 blows my mind.

Comment: Wait, one more thing... the breadcrumb is getting cached on all views with the same title. How can I fix that?

Comment: I got it, I added `route.name` as a cache context.

Comment: yes, and for the title a cache tag of the view, if you want that it gets updated when you change the view.